# Meaning of "contractor’s site"

Tags: contractors

I am applying for a contract position, and the application said:

> Location: Work will be conducted primarily off-site at the contractor’s site

Is this like work at home or at the contract company's office?

Comment: This is ambiguous the way it is written. You need to ask them.

Comment: It’s a bit ambiguous, but you know you will rarely be at the client’s office. Unless you are employed by a contracting company it means at your home, at the office at your home, or at your rented office if you rented one.

Comment: Just for clarity, are there three parties involved here? You, your company, and the client? For the record, in some parts of the world, if you're a contractor, that's usually understood that you are self-employed (so there is no middle-man).

Answer (score 3):

For a vaguely worded phrase like this, the only way to be sure what is meant is to contact the company or recruiter and ask them.

Comment: This has a pretty well understood and standard definition in Government work.

Comment: @JohnFx which government?

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. US Government. We use this language all the time in our contracts. It is a bit odd for an individual contractor vs work contracted out to a firm. Likely someone is just steeped in the jargon and assuming people outside the public sector use it as frequently as they do.

Comment: @JohnFx Probably. I've worked at three different non-US government departments (including as a contractor) and I've never heard the phrase, so it's certainly not universal even within various governments.

Answer (score 1):

This type of specification is generally seen when a company is bidding on a contract. The customer is specifying the location of the work for that position, and the section may also specify any other location requirements. The customer can specify which positions will need to come to the customer location for monthly meetings, demonstrations, and the like. The customer will also specify if they will cover travel time for these meetings, and will pay local or other transportation costs.

So if you are going to have a contract between you and the customer you need to fully understand the work location and transportation issues.

On the other hand if you are going to be an employee of company X and they are wanting to put you on Contract Y with costumer Z, you want to know where they will require you to work. You do want to ask about local and long distance travel requirements. You don't are if the money directly or indirectly comes from the customer, you just care about type of travel, amount of travel, and that time and expenses will be covered by somebody.

Ask for clarification. Always ask for clarification. It is possible that they failed to specify the work location because they were lifting the exact phrase in the contract. It is possible that the company can have multiple work locations, so knowing which one is very important. If have many times worked at a company location 20 miles from my manager. Other times I have worked at a customer site across the street from my manager.